# InterlockedExchange method of kernel32 not found when linking a dll to a c# project

Tags: c#, linker-errors, kernel32

I have a Program in C# under visual studio that was targeting the *.NET Framework 4.5.2*
It is linked with another C# project (a plugin ) that target *4.5.2*. This plugin has a dll in its references, (32 bit).
The programm and the plugin build configuration are set to **Any CPU**

Now I changed the targeted Framework for both of them to *4.7.1*. 
When I launch the Programm, it fails to load the Plugin.
Looking at the dll with dependency walker it looks like it does not find two methods in the *kernel32* library.
See the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9z5A.png)
I am a bit new to C# and I find it weird, and don't really understand what is happening. (How could those method have been found before and not now anymore)..?

Comment: You should try explicitly setting the build configuration,

Comment: That is accurate, it doesn't actually live in kernel32.dll.  The MSDN info is misleading, intentionally, It used to a long time ago.  But so important today in the era of multi-core that they made a macro to cut down on the call overhead.  The .NET jitter treats it the same way, Interlocked.Exchange() is an intrinsic and doesn't actually call the framework method, producing a single processor instruction instead.  Which is what you should use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you reference a 32-bit DLL, you should not be compiling to "Any CPU".  If you run this on a 64-bit machine, your process will run as a 64-bit process and will not be able to load the 32-bit dll.  Compile at least the EXE as 32-bit.  If one module in your process is restricted to 32-bit, then every module in your process needs to be 32-bit (and, if one module is 64-bit, then every module must be 64-bit).

The InterlockedExchange stuff is likely a canard sending you off in the wrong direction (see the note from @HansPassant above).

Don't host screen-shots on remote locations, that web-site is blocked for me, and likely for others as well.

Comment: I'm curious why someone dinged me with a down-vote.  It's odd to be -1 with a checkmark

Comment: @user198530: Did you ever give me an up-vote?  An accepted answer with a "-1" rating is awfully odd.

Comment: Flydog57 I Just did, sorry. However I was not the downvoter for sure. Somebody must have gone frustrated not being the first to answer... I develop under Windows since very recently after years under linux. It is very strange to see that questions and answers related to VS, C#, Developmenter under Windwos generally get downvoted very very quickly without apparent reasons. StackOverflow should really take on this issue and force angry downvoters to leave comments.. otherwise it is non sense

Answer (score 0):

Both Hans Passant and Flydog 57 answer are correct. Giving credit to Flydog57 since it was a bit clearer for a newcomer like me.
Problem I had was eventhough I activate the target Platform as x86 for the whole solution, some subproject stayed as AnyCPU. (They had no x86 Platform and I could not create one for abstruse reasons).
However, forcing everyone to x86 did it.
DependencyWalker was a bit confusing to be, as it keeps writing 64 next to the system librairies name. Coming from Linux world I interpreted it as Problem during the linking, but I understand better now.
Thank you.